# Executar um script através do atributo 'name' não funciona

Tags: jquery

Segue o código:

```
<select class="form-control" name="dd_medidaAplicada" id="dd_medidaAplicada">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="cancelada">Advertência Cancelada</option>
<option value="escrita">Advertência Escrita</option>
<option value="verbal">Advertência Verbal</option>
<option value="dispensa">Dispensa por Justa Causa</option>
<option value="suspensao">Suspensão</option>
```

Eu quero executar um script toda vez que for mudado de item selecionado:

```
$("input[name=dd_medidaAplicada]").on('change', function() { alert( this.value );})
```

Porém, através do atributo name eu não consigo executar. Caso eu utilize o atributo ID, funciona! Segue exemplo:

```
$("#dd_medidaAplicada").on('change', function() { alert( this.value );})
```

Desta forma, o Alert executa sem problemas.
E sim, eu poderia usar o atributo ID, porem muitas vezes este mesmo problema acontece nos meus códigos e cansei de criar uma ID só para executar um código. Quero entender o porque de não executar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O teu seletor está à procura de um `input`, devia estar à procura de um `select`. Para além disso duas observações:

- se tens vários `select`, dá-lhes a mesma classe e usa `$(".form-control").on(`, assim serão todos selecionados
- usa aspas nos seletores, `select[name='dd_medidaAplicada']`

```js
$("select[name='dd_medidaAplicada']").on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="dd_medidaAplicada" id="dd_medidaAplicada">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="cancelada">Advertência Cancelada</option>
    <option value="escrita">Advertência Escrita</option>
    <option value="verbal">Advertência Verbal</option>
    <option value="dispensa">Dispensa por Justa Causa</option>
    <option value="suspensao">Suspensão</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

O elemento não é um `input` e sim um `select`, no jquery existem diversos [tipos de seletores](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), no exemplo abaixo utilizei `name*='dd_medidaAplicada'`, ou seja, qualquer item do select que conter `dd_medidaAplicada` no `name`.

```js
$("select[name*='dd_medidaAplicada']").on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
})
//$("#dd_medidaAplicada").on('change', function() { alert( this.value );})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="dd_medidaAplicada" id="dd_medidaAplicada">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="cancelada">Advertência Cancelada</option>
<option value="escrita">Advertência Escrita</option>
<option value="verbal">Advertência Verbal</option>
<option value="dispensa">Dispensa por Justa Causa</option>
<option value="suspensao">Suspensão</option>
```

Comment: Faltaram só as aspas no seletor.

Comment: @Renan corrigido, valeu!

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!